# Using ng-show and ng-click with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click, ng-show

I have a list of colors (red, blue, green). When `ng-click` on each color, I want to `ng-show` the shades of that color.

My HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat='color in colors' ng-click='color.click'>
  {{color.show}}
</div>
<br><br><br>
<div ng-repeat='color in colors' ng-show='color.show'>
  <div ng-repeat='shade in color.shades'>
    {{shade}}
  </div>
</div>
```

My controller:

```
$scope.colors = [{
    show: 'red',
    click: 'red = true; blue = false; green = false',
    shades: [
      'dark red', 'medium red', 'light red'
    ]
  }, {
    show: 'blue',
    click: 'red = false; blue = true; green = false',
    shades: [
      'dark blue', 'medium blue', 'light blue'
    ]
  }, {
    show: 'green',
    click: 'red = false; blue = false; green = true',
    shades: [
      'dark green', 'medium green', 'light green'
    ]
  }
]
```

Somehow its not working. Possibly something about linking it to the controller. Can you please help me out? A better approach is welcomed.

Here is my [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jk2HepuMFMkO1tsr43ba?p=preview)

Thank you!

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/LHmFL0ZppWNQeVJXbqt9?p=preview

Comment: @Dave Can you help me out a bit? What if I want to have all the shades of all the colors shown when the page loads, but once clicked on a color, only the shade of that color shows? Thank you

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/xuIA30k9jgETyMwUv0xd?p=preview